# How Can I Call Mapquest From My Website with a Starting Point of the Current Location?

Tags: javascript, routes, geolocation, leaflet, mapquest

I currently use the following URL format to display the Mapquest Directions page with the To location populated.

```
http://www.mapquest.com/directions?q=my_full_address_here
```

Using this link the person has to select Current Location as a starting point. I would like for my Mapquest link to include the current location of the user as the starting point if possible.

I have reviewed https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/link-to-mapquest and http://www.mapquestapi.com but so far I did not find anything where I could set Current Location in the URL. From the Mapquest documentation I found that instead of using `q` I can use `q1 & q2` or `q & to:` to provide the from/to locations. However I would have to know the starting location first to set the value for `q1 or to:`.

You can do include the current location within a Google Maps link by using the following link.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/current+location/my_full_address_here
```

Note: I have chosen Mapquest for my mapping application because it has the best mapping information for the area I want to provide directions to. Google Maps cannot find any of the cities I need my website users to be able to produce directions for.

All the results I have found regarding including current location in a link are for Google Maps, not Mapquest. If there is not a function for current location available in Mapquest I would like to know how to find a user's current location to provide in my link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript [Navigator](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) to grab the user's current location and put it in the mapquest.com url.

Comment: I realized that I did not include that I was working on a Ruby on Rails application. I was able to find a solution within Ruby on Rails without using JavaScript after doing a search on Stack Overflow. I can get the longitude and latitude of the current location by using request.location.longitude and request.location.latitude. I need to get the format to include them in my MapQuest link.